# Video element didn't show up after successfully getting local stream WebRTC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc

Currently, I am creating a P2P video call application. And I want when I click the open my camera, then the camera will be opened and the media stream will be fed to my video tag. Here is the code, the file `index.jsx`, some code are suppressed for brevity:

```js
const ForwardRefConference = forwardRef(Conference);
const [localAudioEnabled, setLocalAudioEnabled] = useState(false);
const [localVideoEnabled, setLocalVideoEnabled] = useState(false);
let settings = {
    selectedAudioDevice: "",
    selectedVideoDevice: "",
    resolution: "vga",
    bandwidth: 512,
    codec: "vp8",
    isDevMode: false,
    audio: localAudioEnabled,
    video: localVideoEnabled
};
const startPublishingVideo = (sid, uid) => {
    settings.video = true;
    setLocalVideoEnabled(true);
    conference.current.handleLocalStream();
}

return (
 <div>
 <button
                      className={style.btn_function}
                      onClick={startPublishingVideo}
                    />
{<ForwardRefConference
                    uid={uid}
                    sid={sid}
                    rtc={rtc}
                    peers={peers}
                    vidFit={vidFit}
                    settings={settings}
                    localAudioEnabled={localAudioEnabled}
                    localVideoEnabled={localVideoEnabled}
                    ref={conference}
                  />}</div>)
```

Here is the `Conference` component, which contains the components for rendering video, and here is the part I use the get user media:

```js
const dohandleLocalStream = async () => {
    const { settings, rtc } = props;
    Ion.LocalStream.getUserMedia({
        codec: settings.codec.toUpperCase(),
        resolution: settings.resolution,
        bandwidth: settings.bandwidth,
        // audio: settings.audio,
        // video: settings.video,
        audio: true,
        video: true
      })
        .then((media) => {
          console.log("rtc.publish media=", media);
          rtc.publish(media);
          localStreamObj.stream = media;
          setLocalStreamObj(localStreamObj);
          console.log(
            "got local stream from " + JSON.stringify(localStreamObj.stream)
          );
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log("handleLocalStream error => " + e));

    doMuteMediaTrack("video", props.localVideoEnabled);
};
```

Here is what I return from `Conference`:

```js
return ({localStreamObj.stream && (
        <div className="conference-local-video-layout">
          <LocalVideoView
            key={id + " -video"}
            id={id + "-video"}
            label="Local Stream"
            stream={localStreamObj.stream}
            audioMuted={audioMuted}
            videoMuted={videoMuted}
            videoType="localVideo"
            controls
          />
        </div>
)})
```

And here is the `LocalVideoView`, which will get the stream from `Conference` and render it to the video tag:

```js
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        videoRef.current.srcObject = props.stream;
        console.log('current video stream: ' + JSON.stringify(props.stream));
        return () => {
            if (videoRef.current) {
                videoRef.current.srcObject = null;
            }
        }
    }, []   )

    const {id, label, audioMuted, videoMuted, videoType} = props;

    

    return (
        <div className="local-video-container" style={{borderWidth: `${minimize ? '0px' : '0.5px'}`}}>
            <video
                ref={videoRef} 
                id={id}
                autoPlay
                playsInline
                muted={true}
                className="local-video-size"
            />)
```

When I open my camera, the webcam activated but I still cannot see the video element displayed. As far as I know, when I get the local stream and then I set the state variable `localStreamObj` then the component should be re-render but it won't. And also when I try to get the userMedia right after the page gets loaded, then the video element then displayed. I am not sure why because I'm new to React, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why the video didn't display in the first place. Because of this:

```js
localStreamObj.stream = media;
setLocalStreamObj(localStreamObj);
```

I am mutating the existing object and still setting this old object and that must be a reason why it didn't trigger re-rendering.

When I try to create a new object and set it to the state variable, like this:

```js
const mediaStream = {
   stream: media
}
setLocalStreamObj(mediaStream);
```

Then it works as expected.